# I have Problem with redirection in my php file

Tags: php, curl

I have a PHP file generated video link 
https://tv3lpc.gq/tv3lpc/staple/ost.php?quality=low&num=0
I can run the extracted link directly on VLC but when I put the link inside a PHP file to redirect it doesn't work. I tried to add user agent VLC/2.2.8 LibVLC/2.2.8 But does not work.

```
$url = file_get_contents('https://tv3lpc.gq/tv3lpc/staple/ost.php?quality=low&num=0');
$ch3 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'User-Agent: VLC/2.2.8 LibVLC/2.2.8')
);
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$a = curl_exec($ch3); 
curl_close ($ch3);
header("Location: ". $a);
```

Can anyone guide me what the problem is and test the file by itself

Comment: Your attempt at adding the header should have only gotten you an error, because `$ch` does not exist.

Comment: You should make a debug output to check what $a actually contains - it appears not to be what you thought it was.

Comment: @04FS i edit $ch But does not work  ,how can i do debug please

Comment: _Look at_ what you are actually getting in $a.